# Redirect traffic of one proxy to another one

Tags: iptables, proxy, redirect, traffic-management

I have installed a **v2ray** client on my server and I can connect to it successfully. Assume it is listening on following address:

```
http://localhost:1089
```

I also installed `MTProto` proxy on my server to serve my users:

```
/snap/bin/mtproxy -u mtproxy -p 8888 -H 8000 -S my_secret --aes-pwd proxy-secret proxy-multi.conf -M 1
```

But now I want to send the output traffic of `MTProto` to `v2ray`:

```
 Clients ===> MTProto Proxy ===> v2ray client ===> v2ray server ===> Destination
```

**How can I do this redirection? Can I use `iptable` for this purpose?**